# How to access a structures' members outside of its original function?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am working on a project where I am creating structures inside of a separate function than `main()`. After being created and added member (variable) information into the structure variable, I need to be able to `return` a pointer to the structure in which I can access it for reference and printing.

I am including my code and please be as simple as possible as I am new to structures.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct _car
{
    char color[20];
    char model[20];
    char brand[20];
    int year;
    struct _car *eptr;
} Car;

Car* readCars(char* filename);


/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Car *Cars;
    Car *eptr;

    Cars = readCars(argv[1]);

    printf("%s%s%s%s", Cars->color, Cars->brand, Cars->model, Cars->color);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

Car* readCars(char* filename)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    int year;
    char color [20], model [20], brandx[20];
    Car car1;
    Car car2;
    Car *carptr;
    Car *car2ptr;
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("File cannot be opened\n");
    }
    while(file != EOF)
    {

        fscanf(file, "%s%s%s%d", color, model, brandx, &year);

        strcpy(car1.color, color);
        strcpy(car1.model, model);
        strcpy(car1.brand, brandx);
        car1.year = year;

        carptr = &car1;
        fscanf(file, "%s%s%s%d", color, model, brandx, &year);

        strcpy(car2.color, color);
        strcpy(car2.model, model);
        strcpy(car2.brand, brandx);
        car2.year = year;
        car2ptr = &car2;

        if (fscanf(file, "%s%s%s%d", color, model, brandx, &year) == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return carptr;    
    }
```

Comment: strcpy(cararray[0], car1.color); is it valid ?

Comment: No it's not. Sorry I didn't mean to include it. I've spent so many hours on this I'm not even sure where I am anymore.

Comment: and more errors are there to resolve.

Comment: I've edited to where the program will function and pull data from the struct member car1 but no other members. My intent is to be able to pull all members. I understand all the criticism of this program however I just started programming less than 3 months ago. This project is our assignment for our class and my TA's have been less than helpful so I was hoping to get more help from here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the main question in your post, in the `Car* readCars(char* filename)` function, you're storing the address of a local variable into the pointer

```
carptr = &car1;
```

and then trying to `return` it

```
return carptr;
```

In this case, as soon as the `readCars()` function finisihes execution, the existence of `car` will be ceased and you'll be invoking [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by accessing the returned pointer.

If you want a memory to be valid even outside the scope of it's allocation (in this case, outside `readCars()` function), you need to allocate the same using dynamic memory allocation, for example, [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family.

FWIW, once you've done using the returned pointer, you also need to [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) the memory to avoid [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

---

That said,

1. You never *effectively* checked for the success of `fopen()` or that of  `fscanf()`. If either of them failed, continuing *normally* is the ideal scenario for invoking UB.
2. [`while ( !feof (fp) )` is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)
3. Pointer arithmetic(s) in your code is(are) *meaningless*.
4. You've got syntax errors...and maybe more.

Comment: I'm able to get the first member of the structs information. I've edited my post...I added the wrong file. I did at some point had a check for file but not fscanf. But just to be clear if I malloc for carptr I'll be able to view all members of the struct. I'm not sure I was 100% clear on asking that question. I want to be able to access the whole struct and members outside of its current scope. Even if I malloc how would I achieve that? Also thanks for the fast answer.